# What's the right term for the list of "X killed Y with Z" messages in a multiplayer shooter?

Tags: terminology

It's probably obvious from the title, but I'm specifically thinking of messages like

> ProGamer64 [image of shotgun] L33tCamper

that appear in the bottom right corner when a kill happens, then fade away after a few seconds.

Is there a standard term for these messages or the list of them?

Comment: Obviously they should be called: Death notes  d:

Comment: @aslum It's more like a reverse Death Note actually - after a person dies, it details when, where and how that person died.

Comment: I remember this was called "killspam" and CoD called it killfeed many years later which was easier to find in search engine results, so it took over.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is known as the **killfeed**.

This term has been widely used throughout many different multiplayer games, including old ones such as Quake, Counter-Strike, Starsiege's Tribes, etc. For the etymology of the word the origin is unknown but it has likely started off with Quake/Quake II.

Some examples of killfeed from the games you have mentioned:

[image]

From [Giant Bomb](http://www.giantbomb.com/kill-feed/3015-5490/):

> A standard in nearly all competitive online shooters, the Kill Feed is
>   the live on-screen update of the kills in an multiplayer game,
>   providing updates as to whom is killing whom, as well as other
>   important events.

Comment: Fairly certain Call of Duty was neither the first to introduce the system nor the first to name it as such.

Comment: @Nit Thanks for the clarification. Edited to further reflect that.

Comment: Oh snap! Sorry I didn't respond to you the other day :P

Comment: I thought it was "kill log"

Answer (score 11):

I've never heard of "killfeed", but then I haven't been into games in a while. In Quake (the first one) they were called obituaries.

[See here](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/master/qw-qc/client.qc#L1225) for the list of Quake's obituary messages, including such classics as "X rides Y's rocket", "X accepts Y's shaft", and "X chewed on Y's boomstick".

Comment: An Obituary would be an individual entry in the Kill Feed.

Comment: Good point. In Quake they were listed in a general notification area, interspersed with other messages such as "You picked up ammo", "So-and-so connected/disconnected", and player chat. My guess is that it was in Half-Life that the obituaries first got their own dedicated corner of the screen. I'm more certain that Half-Life was the originator of using the rather unpoetic weapon icon. The following year, Quake3 and Unreal Tournament were still using descriptive obituaries, but most modern FPSes seem to be derived from the HL/Counter-Strike school.

Answer (score 7):

In some games, these messages are known as "Obituaries".

Comment: Just curious, which game has it as the "Obituary"? Sounds like a really funny game to me :)

Comment: @0-framelinks It's just what I've always heard them called. I want to say Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory, Unreal Tournament 2004, and Starsiege: Tribes but the most solid evidence I could find was some patch notes for Enemy Territory: Legacy which reference changes to obituary message. Unfortunately, it's rather difficult to find what I'm looking for by searching for "obituaries".

Comment: Looks like the ETPro mod for WolfET (or at least parts of the ET community at the time) also called them obituaries: http://etpro.anime.net/playerguide.html

Comment: Per narb's answer, the original Quake source code referred to them internally as obituaries. I don't believe that name was ever made user-facing, but the late-90s Quake modding community would have understood the term.

Comment: Red Orchestra: Ostfront and it's mods refer to them as obituaries as well.

Comment: @0-framelinks CoD4 has a `ui_hud_obituaries` configuration variable for toggling the visibility of the obituaries.

Comment: I'm not surprised that the name "obituaries" would have stuck, since both Half-Life games as well as many (or all?) of the Call of Duty and Medal of Honor games, and of course the Enemy Territory games, were originally derived from Quake's source code. I am curious what UT and Tribes would have called them internally.

Answer (score 5):

The area where kill notifications are posted is called the "Killboard" in many games including TF2 and Eve Online.

Comment: Is the name 'Killboard' seen somewhere in these games? Or material (help files/wikis/commenteries) related to them?

Answer (score 5):

Killfeed is the correct answer however it is a term much that is much older than Cod and probably dates back to quake, I know I knew of it long before COD exsisted.
The results you are seeing are biased due to popularity of search terms and lack of inter-generational gaming history.
The first COD game was in 2006 and the term kill feed was widely used before then. Google dates the term 'kill feed' back as far as feb 2004 but has no prior data to that. The term 'killfeed' dates back to 2010 where we also see a spike in usage of 'kill feed'. This corresponds with the release of COD: Black Ops.

Another example of this bias from an article saying Starsiege:Tribes has a notable kill feed with custom messages e.g. 'Player A blasts Player B with the Spinfusor'.
However the quake series did this first including custom environmental deaths 'PlayerName Melted' when you fall in lava for example.

Its possible its as old as Doom!

Answer (score 0):

I usually call that a "killfeed" as well, but have also heard it referred to as the "log". This makes sense, as it documents what's been happening in the game.